# Installing LMMS 1.0.3 on Ubuntu

Tags: make, tar, cmake, lmms

I'm having problems installing LMMS using cmake. I downloaded the tar file, and created the build folder inside of the extracted directory, then run cmake. I've attached the error log at the bottom. I'm a beginner when it comes to Ubuntu, so I'd appreciate any help. I've tried using the Software Center, but it has an older version of LMMS.

Thanks!

```
Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" failed.
Compiler: /home/joseph/anaconda/bin/clang++ 
Build flags: 
Id flags: 

The output was:
1
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


Determining if the CXX compiler works failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/joseph/Desktop/lmms-1.0.3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec633473811/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec633473811.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec633473811.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/joseph/Desktop/lmms-1.0.3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/joseph/Desktop/lmms-1.0.3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec633473811.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
/home/joseph/anaconda/bin/clang++     -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec633473811.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /home/joseph/Desktop/lmms-1.0.3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
Linking CXX executable cmTryCompileExec633473811
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec633473811.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/home/joseph/anaconda/bin/clang++        CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec633473811.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o  -o cmTryCompileExec633473811 -rdynamic 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec633473811] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/joseph/Desktop/lmms-1.0.3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec633473811/fast] Error 2


Determining if files soundcard.h exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/joseph/Desktop/lmms-1.0.3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec4188567017/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4188567017.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4188567017.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/joseph/Desktop/lmms-1.0.3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/joseph/Desktop/lmms-1.0.3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4188567017.dir/CheckIncludeFiles.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4188567017.dir/CheckIncludeFiles.c.o   -c /home/joseph/Desktop/lmms-1.0.3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFiles.c
/home/joseph/Desktop/lmms-1.0.3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFiles.c:2:23: fatal error: soundcard.h: No such file or directory
 #include <soundcard.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec4188567017.dir/CheckIncludeFiles.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/joseph/Desktop/lmms-1.0.3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec4188567017/fast] Error 2

Source:
/* */
#include <soundcard.h>


int main(){return 0;}

Determining if files process.h exist failed with the following output:
Change Dir: /home/joseph/Desktop/lmms-1.0.3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec3312614237/fast"
/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3312614237.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3312614237.dir/build
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/joseph/Desktop/lmms-1.0.3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /home/joseph/Desktop/lmms-1.0.3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3312614237.dir/CheckIncludeFiles.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -o CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3312614237.dir/CheckIncludeFiles.c.o   -c /home/joseph/Desktop/lmms-1.0.3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFiles.c
/home/joseph/Desktop/lmms-1.0.3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CheckIncludeFiles.c:2:21: fatal error: process.h: No such file or directory
 #include <process.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec3312614237.dir/CheckIncludeFiles.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/joseph/Desktop/lmms-1.0.3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
make: *** [cmTryCompileExec3312614237/fast] Error 2

Source:
/* */
#include <process.h>


int main(){return 0;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install LMMS 1.0.3 in Ubuntu 14.04 and 14.10 without difficult compilations with [**ppa:israeldahl/lmms-1.0.3**](https://launchpad.net/~israeldahl/+archive/ubuntu/lmms-1.0.3) repository.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:israeldahl/lmms-1.0.3

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install lmms
```

Comment: 1.03 is not a stable version (it is for Utopic not trusty or lower)